# Is it possible to have a higher power GPU integrated into the motherboard?

Tags: gpu, graphics

This is an idea ive been pondering for a bit in my spare time, but i have no hardware engineering knowledge to know if this is just crazy or if its a possibility.

Is it possible to integrate a high powered GPU into the motherboard? Instead of having a PCIe connection for the board to interface with an external card, im imagining having the board be uniquely built to have a graphics processor like that's used the Nvidia's Maxwell line (GM107 is what i think it is) integrated directly into the motherboard, along with all the bits and bobbles to make it work properly.

I know there have been integrated graphics on motherboards in the past but nothing with any decent oomph behind it from what i can tell.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Yes.  This sort of thing is done routinely in high performance (gaming, CAD) laptops.

Comment: Yes. Big drawback : it's much harder to upgrade. And if upgrading doesn't matter to you, you're probably not interested in the fastest GPU in the first place. Which makes the market for such a MB vanishingly small.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to integrate a high powered GPU into the motherboard?

Yes. Yes it is.

The motherboard would be quite large, because instead of a neat little PCI-E slot, the entire circuit for the GPU would need to be incorporated onto an already extremely dense 2D plane (PCB layouts are pretty hectic with motherboards). It is quite handy how motherboards can slot in the already individually large and complex PCB of a GPU, allowing external power supply pins as well. You lose a lot by integrating the design, so why do it? Thermal issues are huge too, don't forget.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, but have you wondered why the past integrated graphics controllers were small and lacked power? Modern graphics cards are the size they are for a reason - they process enormous amounts of data and produce lots of heat. Actually, a majority of their size is due to heatsinking and copper heat piping. So, yes, this could be done but the motherboards would have to be even larger than they already are. Plus, what is the benefit of integrating the graphics as opposed to a dedicated and upgradable alternative? –